# ThinkPad Universal Thunderbolt 4 Dock (40B0) - second external monitor black (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, docking

A few days ago purchased device https://support.lenovo.com/lt/en/downloads/ds554336.

Windows works perfectly.

Ubuntu 22.04. In the settings, I see three displays (notebook + monitors). One of them is a black screen.

ThinkPad docking has been updated to the latest firmware version.

```
Kernel: 5.19.17-051917-generic
```

Next I tried to use the latest kernel

```
6.3.1-060301-generic
```

Two monitors enabled into docking (DP port).
On ubuntu 22.04 LTS boot I see only two monitors (left works, right black screen).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling "Daisy Chain" in all monitors, even if they are not chained. If supported, this can be found in the setting of the monitor itself, not in the operating system.

(Had same problem with the same ThinkPad dock and Fujitsu P27-8 TS Pro monitor)